Verifying the contents of a linked list
In my contract, I need to keep track of an ordered list of addresses based on some parameter. To avoid excessive use of storage I have opted for a linked list where each address records in a mapping the previous and the next address. This makes it cheap to maintain the list, however when I need to load the first 100 addresses I need to perform 100 sload operations, which is not cheap at all. Is there any other way to read or verify the contents of the list? Submitting the list as an argument to a function and verifying using a hash also does not seem like a solution, since I will have to load the list at another point of my logic.

Reading contents means reading 100 addresses from the storage, so there is no way you can make it cheaper, because the main cost is accessing the storage. When you say "verify" is in unclear what you mean - using algorithms like Merkle tree can make verifying structures faster.

In a general rule, if it is too expensive, switch to a cheaper, more efficient, blockchain.

Thank you, My list could in theory host thousands of entries but I want to read only the first 100. One way is to perform 100 sloads but that's expensive. Another way is that I fetch the addresses from the contract and I submit them to my function as arguments. I cannot however see a way to verify that the input is indeed the first 100 addresses without loading the addresses.

How about just init the first 100 addresses as const variables? And there is a cheaper solution that use the hash of the previous address as the storage slot for the next address. The linkedlist logic of the first 100 addresses can be handled separately.
